# Node processes and replication across multiple nodes

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, deployment, replication, docker-swarm

I have a containerized Node app, which runs on a DigitalOcean server. When I update the app on the server, the app has to go down for a small amount of time. In order to be able to update the app and avoid downtime, I am currently reading on zero-downtime deployment / blue green deployment with the intention of integrating Docker Swarm and Kubernetes as soon as I am more confident in my ability to use them.

But there is something that really confuses me when I imagine my app being replicated across several nodes. In my application, a User can define some Rules. So, for example, every day at 11AM, I want an email to be sent to Bob.

When my application starts, it fetches all CronTriggers from the database and builds CronTrigger objects that live in the app.

```
const { CronJob } = require('cron');

module.exports = class CronTrigger {
  constructor(cronString) {
    this.job = new CronJob(cronString, () => {

      // Send email here

    }, null, false, 'America/Toronto');
    this.job.start();
  }
}
```

But what happens if my app is replicated across several nodes? Does that mean that the CronTrigger will be executed as many times as there are nodes? If I have a 3-nodes cluster, how can I make sure that at 11AM, only one email will be sent to Bob and not 3?

How is this kind of problem dealt with with technologies such as Docker Swarm, Kubernetes or even AWS EC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you fix this by either moving the actual cron execution to a different daemon that you only run one copy of or use some kind of leader election system so that only one of the copies runs them at any given time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @coderanger! In the first case, then I would go back to my original problem, which is whenever I need to update the service/daemon, it will have to go down for a while. Only, it would now be on a subset of my back-end so it is still a plus. In the second case, do you know if it's something that can be done with Docker Swarm?

Comment: There is no magic here, if you run multiple copies of your code, then you run multiple copies. Kube vs. Swarm is not going to change that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In my last sentence, I meant "Do you know if the leader election system you were talking about in your answer is something that can be done in Docker Swarm or Kubernetes?"

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/01/simple-leader-election-with-kubernetes/ is an example that's in JS of using a sidecar with the K8s leader election API. I don't think the API is directly exposed in the JS client libraries, but that should be a starting point.